# Tab completion ignoring some files in Bash/Debian

Tags: bash, vim, tab-completion

I am using tab completion in a standard Debian install with Bash and I have some files being ignored. For example, if I have the files:

```
index.php
index.php.a
```

If I type `vim i` then `tab` it immediately selects "index.php " (see space after file name). Normally, it would just complete up to "index.php" and give me the option to type something else after.

Why is it behaving differently in this situation?

**Update**

Some commands such as "cp" seem to handle the tab completion just fine, so maybe it is vim looking for specific file extensions?

Comment: what happens if you have just index.php.a?

Comment: @MicheleDorigatti tab completion (with vim) does not see it.

Comment: You can check what happens under the hood with `complete -p vim`, and then `type` on the function name it shows you. For me, `vim` tab completion is just a default file name completion function, `_filedir_xspec` – see [here](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/c51ccb76d1f4fa08f1260e8d204d3622dce76f4e/bash_completion#L1954). My guess is that extensions commonly associated with backup copies are ignored on purpose.

Comment: My question was closed, However, the answers on the other page do not seem to answer my question.

Comment: Specifically, [here](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/c51ccb76d1f4fa08f1260e8d204d3622dce76f4e/bash_completion#L2049) you can see what gets ignored for `vim`, including filenames ending in `.a`.

Comment: @kojow7 Your question is "why does a specific command not complete all files" right? It's because of the third party "bash-completion" package, and the duplicate explains this and how to disable custom completion for a command on a per-completion or per-command basis

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thank you very much. That is very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bash-completion](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion) package uses the function [`_filedir_xspec`](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/c51ccb76d1f4fa08f1260e8d204d3622dce76f4e/bash_completion#L1954) to complete `vim`. That function in general completes filenames, but excludes certain patterns depending on which command it is completing.

For `vim`, the [exclusion pattern](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/bash_completion#L2049) starts like this:

```sh
_install_xspec '*.@([ao]|so|so.!(conf|*/*) ...
```

I.e., among other things, files ending in `.a` should be ignored. The thinking behind that is probably that these are often created as backup copies and you probably don't *want* to edit them.

If you want to override this behaviour, you can add your own completions into `~/.bash_completion`; for example, to get vim to complete on all filenames, use this:

```sh
complete -f vim
```

which will make `vim` tab completion default to the built-in file completion bevahiour.